# "One has to die one death"

Tags: idiom-requests

I'm looking for an English equivalent to the German "Einen Tod muss man sterben" ("One has to die one death"). As far as I know the literal translation is not in use.

It refers to a situation in which there are several options, but all of them include an unavoidable, very adverse component. This adverse factor is so inherent to the situation that it is compared to death, which is an unavoidable part of life - one may just chose which kind of death one wants to die.

Comment: I don't speak German, but it is possible that this idiom is equivalent to "Damned if you do, damned if you don't"?

Comment: I don't know what contexts the Germans use that phrase in, but perhaps it's equivalent to ***A man's gotta do what a man's gotta do*** or ***Everybody's gotta die sometime***.

Comment: Perhaps you can find an adequate answer to your question by scouring the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_expressions_related_to_death) on expressions related to death.

Comment: Let's not forget "Cowards die many times before their deaths.
The valiant never taste of death but once."  (Some old English guy wrote that, I understand.)

Comment: @Sawbones That's almost exactly it. It only appears to be missing that there may be more than two options.

Comment: Could it be that the word-order [which can be varied in German  -  it could have been "Man muss einen Tod sterben"] is emphasizing the *Einen*  -  that is, it means "You only have to die *once*"?

Comment: @DavidGarner I don't think so - I believe it rather stresses that there _is_ one. I've never heard it in the different order you proposed.

Comment: @mafu, I have only high-school German [50 years ago] so I'll give way on that.  But could you confirm that, though it's not a proverb, "Man muss einen Tod sterben" is good German?  I'd just like to know!

Comment: @DavidGarner "Man muss einen Tod sterben" sounds completely fine to me.

Comment: I'm a bit late to the party, but having lived in Germany and having heard the expression often, I think it expresses the idea that nothing is perfect, and as a consequence one has to accept some things that are not exactly as desired ... indeed, that one should expect this to be the case.

Comment: A bit late here, but "you're going to pay the piper no matter what" is an extended "pay the piper" idiom. The piper in question is the one who accompanies your corpse in your funeral procession, so pretty near the mark.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't believe we have an idiom exactly like that, but the following seem related:

- 'To be between a rock and a hard place' - To be in an impossible dilemma, facing two undesirable choices.
- 'To be between the devil and the deep blue sea' - As above.  Rarer.
- 'Damned if you do, damned if you don't' - Facing a possible action, with negative consequences if it is taken, and (different) negative consequences if it is not.
- 'Lesser of two evils' - The least unappealing of two unpleasant options.
- 'Any port in a storm' - A situation so bad that any solution is acceptable.
- 'To be on the horns of dilemma' - Similar to the German phrase you describe.  Perhaps the closest translation here, but the idiom is quite rarely used.

Comment: Very good ones. I was not aware of 'to be on the horns of dilemma'.

Comment: +1 And [*between Scylla and Charybdis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Between_Scylla_and_Charybdis)

Answer (score 5):

To keep the idea of death:

Pick your poison.

Comment: Great idea and even almost 'literally' equivalent :)

Answer (score 3):

There is a widely used trope in the US, *[it is a good day to die](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_good_day_to_die)*. Attributed (probably falsely) to Crazy Horse, an American Indian leader, to suggest that the warriors were prepared to go to battle even though death was likely.

Numerous film and literary works have co-opted the phrase, or parts of it, often as a title.

It is reminiscent of the Latin phrase often translated as *[Hail Emperor, we who are about to die salute you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ave_Imperator,_morituri_te_salutant)*. Ironically, some historians report that the combatants uttering the phrase then sought to avoid battle but were spurred on by the emperor.

Comment: Actually, the gladiators said " *those* who will die, salute you" (morituri te salutant). They never acknowledged their own death or failure, but were just required to all state it (since some of them would). It's similar to how saying "may the best man win" to your opponent before a match doesn't mean you acknowledge you expect to lose.

Comment: @Flater According to the linked reference, both versions are reported. If the *good day to die* quote is real, I suspect there may have been some companions of the speaker who disagreed.

Answer (score 2):

**This won't end well.** Regardless of what you do, the results will be bad. It's usually used slightly ironically, in the sense that the speaker believes that the actor really ought to know what's going to happen.

Comment: I think the usage is actually quite similar, though it lacks the 'various options' character.